# Distribute values from a map to an array in a balanced way

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to get a balancing algorithm but struggling to understand how to acheieve this.

I have a HashMap as below:

```
Map criteria = new HashMap();
criteria.put("0",5);
criteria.put("1",8);
criteria.put("2",0);
criteria.put("3",7);
...
```

Also, I have a two-dimensional array where I need to have the values fetched from the HashMap and put into the array in a balanced way.

```
String[][] arr = new String[3][1];
```

The end result I am looking for is something like this:

```
arr[0][0]="0"; (the key of the hashmap)
arr[1][0]="1";
arr[2][0]="2,3"; (as the key "2" has the value less among the first two entries, the key "3" should be appended top this node)
```

So, basically the keys of the HashMap should get evenly distributed into the Array based on its values.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve? They way you willbe doing it will make it a bit messy.

Comment: Please explain a bit more. For example what influence the values in the map have and what you mean by "balanced".

Comment: The Map will be populated by an external program. I have a method that will be receiving this method. The Map will contain the keys "0" to "9" as Strings and the corresponding values, which will be varying.                                                              The Array basically signifies nodes,and based on the Map values, I want to assign the nodes in such a way that each of the nodes have approximately equal loads

Comment: Since the map is being provided externally, guess this is the only logic that can be applied for balancing the nodes.